# No se muestra la gráfica con chart.js

Tags: typescript, chart.js

estoy intentado mostrar una gráfica con los valores calculados, pero no se visualiza. Si le pongo los datos directamente, sí lo hace.
Esta es la declaración de variables, lo he intentado de dos maneras, una de ellas está comentada.

```
//Variable con los datasets de los gráficos
//datasets: [{ label: string, data: [{ x: string, y: number }] }] = [{ label: '', data: [{ x: '', y: 0 }] }];
  datasets: [{ label: string, data: number[] }] = [{ label: '', data: [] }];
//Variable para el objeto data de cada dataset a mostrar en el grafico
//data: [{ x: string, y: number }] = [{ x: '', y: 0 }];
  data: number[]=[];
//Array con las etiquetas del eje x del gráfico
  etiquetas: string[] = [];
```

Los cargo con:

```
this.data.push( Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()) );
this.etiquetas.push(this.fecha.toString());
```

y se visualizan así en el explorador, primero las etiquetas y luego los datos(variable res igual al datasets declarado).
[image: resultado por pantalla]

El caso es que no me visualiza nada

```
console.log("antes del grafico:",this.etiquetas, res);
    Chart.register(...registerables);
    let canvasCo2 = document.getElementById('grafico') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    let grafico = new Chart(canvasCo2, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels:this.etiquetas,
      // labels:["uno","dos","tres","cuatro","cinco","seis","siete","ocho","nueve","diez","once","doce","trece","catorce","quince"],
       datasets: res
          //datasets:[{
          //  label:'mi label',
          //  data:[10,15,10,34,21,31,11,21,43,13,41,32,23,22,33,16],
        // },
         //{
          // label:'mi label2',
           //data:[20,25,30],
        //}
       //]
      }
    });
    console.log("Grafico pintado")
```

en res tengo los datasets.
Si uso la parte comentada con los valores directamente, si sale la gráfica.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias de antemano.

PORQUE SON DISTINTAS ESTAS DOS VARIABLES SI AMBAS SON ARRAYS DE OBJETOS?
RES pone [] y prueba [{}]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

"RES antes de gráfico" está declarado como [{}].

CÓDIGO COMPLETO

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DispService } from 'src/app/servicios/disp.service';
import { InformeService } from 'src/app/servicios/informe.service';
import { MedidasCo2Service } from 'src/app/servicios/medidasCo2.service';
import moment from 'moment/moment.js';
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-informe-medidas-co2',
  templateUrl: './informe-medidas-co2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./informe-medidas-co2.component.css']
})
export class InformeMedidasCo2Component implements OnInit {
  //Variable con los datasets de los gráficos
  //datasets: [{ label: string, data: [{ x: string, y: number }] }] = [{ label: '', data: [{ x: '', y: 0 }] }];
  //datasets: [{ label: string, data: number[], borderColor:string }] = [{ label: '', data: [], borderColor:'' }];
  //newDataset: {label:string, data:number[], borderColor: string } = {label:'', data:[], borderColor:''};
  //Variable para el objeto data de cada dataset a mostrar en el grafico
  //data: [{ x: string, y: number }] = [{ x: '', y: 0 }];
  data: number[]=[];
  //Array con las etiquetas del eje x del gráfico
  etiquetas: string[] = [];
  //Fecha con la hora para calcular las medias de las medidas de esa hora
  fecha: string = formatDate('01/01/1900 00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', 'es');
  //Contador de medidas por hora, irá de 1 a 12 que son las máximas
  contaMedidasHora: number = 0;
  //variable con el co2 medio calculado
  co2: number = 0;
  //Variable que indica si se tiene que grabar la medida con la media de la hora
  grabar: boolean = false;
  //Conversión de fechas a tipo date válido
  fdesde: Date = new Date();
  fhasta: Date = new Date();
  //Variable para grabar la ultima medida calculada
  fultima: string = '';
  //Variable para obtener aleatoriamente un color de línea del gráfico
  color: string = "#";

  constructor(private medidasCo2Service: MedidasCo2Service,
    private informeService: InformeService,
    private dispService: DispService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fdesde = new Date(moment(this.informeService.parametros.fdesde, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS').format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00'));
    this.fhasta = new Date(moment(this.informeService.parametros.fhasta, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS').format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59'));
    let datasets=[{}];
    // Chart.register(...registerables);
    // let canvasCo2 = document.getElementById('grafico') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    // console.log("antes del grafico:");
    // let grafico = new Chart(canvasCo2, {
    //   type: 'line',
    //   data: {
    //     labels:this.etiquetas,
    //     datasets:[]
    //    }
    // });


    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("2.calculando medidas");
      //Inicializamos el array de datasets del gráfico, habrá tantos como códigos de dispositivos ha seleccionado en la pantalla
      datasets.splice(0, datasets.length);
      //Recorrer el array con los códigos de dispositivos
      for (let i = 0; i < this.informeService.parametros.codigos.length; i++) {
        //this.newDataset.label = this.dispService.getNombre(this.informeService.parametros.codigos[i]),
        //this.newDataset.borderColor = this.obtenerColor();
        //Buscar las medidas por dispositivo
        this.medidasCo2Service.getMedidas(this.informeService.parametros.codigos[i]).subscribe((data: { status: number; respuesta: any[]; }) => {
          //Si ha encontrado medidas
          if (data.status == 200) {
            //Filtrar las medidas por las fechas seleccionadas como parámetros en la pantalla
            let respuesta_corta = data.respuesta.filter((x: { createdAt: string | number | Date; }) => {
              return new Date(x.createdAt).getTime() >= this.fdesde.getTime()
                && new Date(x.createdAt).getTime() <= this.fhasta.getTime();
            });
            //Inicializar el array con las medidas de cada dispositivo
            this.data.splice(0, this.data.length);
            //Con cada medida se calculan las medias por hora y se graban en el array de datos
            for (let j = 0; j < respuesta_corta.length; j++) {
              this.calcularMediasHora(formatDate(respuesta_corta[j].createdAt, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:00', 'es'), Number(respuesta_corta[j].CO2));
              this.fultima = formatDate(respuesta_corta[j].createdAt, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:00', 'es');
            }
            //Se ha finalizado el bucle sin grabar la última medida
            this.data.push( Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()) );
            //this.newDataset.data.push(Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()));
            this.etiquetas.push(this.fultima.toString());
            //Una vez calculadas todas las medias por hora de todas las medidas encontradas
            //para ese dispositivo entre las fechas seleccionadas, se graba el dataset para 
            //el grafico.
            datasets[i]={
               label: this.dispService.getNombre(this.informeService.parametros.codigos[i]),
               data: this.data,
              //data: [5,10,15,20,41,23,34,15,63,21],
               borderColor: this.obtenerColor()
            };
            //grafico.config.data.datasets.push(this.newDataset);
            //grafico.config.data.labels=this.etiquetas;
          }
        });
      }
      console.log("antes de resolve:", datasets);
      resolve(datasets);
    });

    console.log('1. Proceso iniciado..');

    p.then(res => {
      console.log("3.RES:", res)
      this.verGrafico(res);
      //grafico.update();
    })
  }

  calcularMediasHora(hora: string, co2: number) {
    if (this.fecha == "01/01/1900 00:00") {
      this.fecha = hora;
    }
    if (this.fecha != hora) {
      //se ha cambiado de hora, se guardan los valores almacenados 
      //y se inicia nueva hora con los nuevos valores
      this.data.push( Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()) );
      this.etiquetas.push(this.fecha.toString());
      //this.newDataset.data.push(Number((this.co2 / this.contaMedidasHora).toFixed()));

      this.co2 = co2;
      this.contaMedidasHora = 1;
      this.fecha = hora;
    } else { //es la misma hora, se acumulan los datos
      this.grabar = false;
      this.co2 += co2;
      this.contaMedidasHora++;
    }
  }

  verGrafico(res: any): boolean {
    //Visualizamos los gráficos
    Chart.register(...registerables);
    let canvasCo2 = document.getElementById('grafico') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    console.log("ETIQUETAS antes del grafico:",this.etiquetas);
    console.log("RES antes grafico", res);
    let prueba = [
      {
      borderColor: "#7C66B2",
      data:  this.data,
      label: "con medidas"
      },
      {
        borderColor: "#7C6623",
        data:  [467,345,654,465,544],
        label: "con medidas 2222"
      }
    ];
    console.log("prueba:",prueba);
    let grafico = new Chart(canvasCo2, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels:this.etiquetas,
        //datasets:res
        datasets: prueba
       }
    });
    console.log("Grafico pintado")
    return true;
  }

  obtenerColor():string {
    let color: string = "#";
    let simbolos: string = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      color = color + simbolos[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
    }
    return color;
  }
}
```

EDICION:
He utilizado ng2-chart y se visualiza sin problemas la gráfica con los mismos datos.

Comment: ¿Cómo son los valores de `res`? ¿Ya son un objeto como el que especifica el ejemplo? Es decir es un arreglo de objetos que contiene un label, y otra propiedad llamada data que es un arreglo. ¿Podrías publicar como es el objeto res?

Comment: res es lo que devuelve la promesa donde tengo metidos todos los cálculos de los valores, res = this.datasets, es lo que se visualiza en la imagen capturada de la consola, después de las etiquetas de la fechas.           
         datasets: [{ label: string, data: number[] }] = [{ label: '', data: [] }];

Comment: Qué pasa si comentas la línea de las etiquetas? 

Comment: comentando las etiquetas sigue sin salir, no le gusta nada mi variable datasets, es muy raro

Comment: Puedes poner tus variables como texto? Me gustaría ver que estás mandando cómo `res`. Crees que puedas poner todo como un texto para ver si hay algo extraño?

Comment: He probado otra forma más de hacerlo, siguiendo lo encontrado en stackoverflow, pero ni con esas, sigue sin salir nada ni dar error, he puesto el código completo por si puede ser de ayuda

Comment: Si en labels usas el código que comentaste y de igual forma, en datasets usas el código que comentaste, ¿el gráfico funciona?

Comment: no funciona tampoco. He realizado una prueba creando una variable array de datos antes del gráfico, y metiéndole a mano los datos de this.data y valores para borderColor y label y funciona, pero sacando el console.log de la variable prueba y de mi res he visto una diferencia: en prueba pone [{...}] y luego los valores y en res pone [] y luego los mismos valores, no sé por qué pero me da que tiene algo que ver con que no se visualice, edito la pregunta y adjunto imagen de ello.

Comment: En res esta poniendo un arreglo vació mientras que en prueba un arreglo de objetos.

Comment: RES antes de gráfico tiene datos, puse una imagen de lo que me sale por consola, pero lo pone definido como arreglo, aunque tiene un objeto dentro, sin embargo la prueba por consola la define como arreglo de objetos. Añadí una imagen para ver la diferencia.

Comment: Son diferentes en presentación por el tamaño del array. Pero son el mismo tipo de objeto.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124951/discussion-between-jacobo-and-ana-cristina-bernal).